# pyspark writeStream: Each Data Frame row in a separate json file

Tags: spark-streaming, pyspark

I am using pyspark to read data from a Kafka topic as a streaming dataframe as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("Spark Structured Streaming from Kafka") \
  .getOrCreate()

sdf = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "test") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("parsed_value"))

sdf_ = sdf.select("parsed_value.*")
```

My goal is to write each of the `sdf_` rows as **seperate** json files.
The following code:

```
writing_sink = sdf_.writeStream \
    .format("json") \
    .option("path", "/Desktop/...") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/Desktop/...") \
    .start()

writing_sink.awaitTermination()
```

will write several rows of the dataframe within the same json, depending on the size of the micro-batch (or this is my hypothesis at least).
What I need is to tweak the above so that each row of the dataframe is written in a separate json file.

I have also tried using `partitionBy('column')`, but still this will not do exactly what I need, but instead create folders within which the json files might still have multiple rows written within them (if they have the same id).

Any ideas that could help out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a little confused here! Why do you need a file per row? That doesn't make any sense at first. Sorry my confusion!

Comment: @AndreCarneiro OK sounds like a fair point. But why wouldn't I want that?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, off course! But, normally is expected that similar data stay organized in many rows in a file(unless you need to split it by size, for example). But, as I don't have any idea how  your data is organized I was curious about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that the following option does the trick:

```
   .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1)
```